# Group analysis forbids band-crossing in 1D?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, spacetime-dimensions, group-theory

Group analysis forbids band-crossing in 1D in terms of conventional band theory. I read this in a good [solid state physics book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123850304). But there's no explanation at all. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether the following explanation is relevant for your question:

Generally speaking, according to the *von Neumann-Wigner theorem (no-crossing theorem)*, for a band structure, the band-crossing usually happens in 3D system. But there is also [possibility](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60132/a-question-on-the-existence-of-dirac-points-in-graphene) for the so-called *accidental degeneracy* in **low dimensions** which may result from symmetry.