# Symmetry argument about degeneracy of graphene energy band at Dirac point

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, graphene

This question is very related to the thread [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60132/a-question-on-the-existence-of-dirac-points-in-graphene).

In the answer given by @BebopButUnsteady , the statement is that as long as the inversion and time-reversal symmetry are respected, the Dirac points will exist.

I would like to know a more detailed explanation about this argument, is this degeneracy related to Kramer pairs? Or to small groups?